# Which branching strategy are suitable for our team

Tags: git, github, version-control, workflow, git-flow

Now, we are using SVN as version control, we got tickets from customer (include new feature and bug fixing), all developers commit the changed code to `trunk`, and deploy all change to QA environment for testing. However, not all of tickets are go live to production, some features need more approval from customer or need more testing before release, so we have to pick some commit from trunk and port back to a `release` branch. The source code in `release` branch will be production.

Every release time we have to pick the commit from trunk, and ofcourse we will have so many conflict (because some commits are missing if they are not priority for release), we have to resolve the conflict manually.

Now, we decide to move the code base to Git and need to introduce new workflow to make everything go smoothly, including release time, as little as possible the conflict between release branch and develop branch.

Anyone have experience on this area, please give me some suggestion which workflow should be applied. Following are some mandatory requirement:

- All new feature or bug fix should be available to deploy to QA environment for testing, that mean we should have a branch which contain all changes
- At release time, not all of stories are released, only some commits are picked and ported back

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in the **GitFlow** branching model which supports Release branches, Hotfix branches, and Features branches.

This **[post](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)** describes the proposal and provide detailed explanations regarding how to leverage git in order to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks @nulltoken, however my main problem is `picking` commit from develop to master branch for release, this step has too much conflict if some stories are not required to release at that time. We need to introduce a workflow which help us solve this prblem

Comment: "not all of stories are released" -> Actually you may be willing to *not* rely on the source control to do this as you will encounter conflicts and dependencies at the code level between commits. How about rather dealing with this at the product level, through something like the **[FeatureToggle](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FeatureToggle.html)** concept that would allow you to control in production whether or not a feature is activated?

Comment: @KhoiNguyen this is the aim of Git Flow. Develop should always be stable and releasable, so only 'fully approved' features would be merged into develop. All other, unapproved or incomplete features reside in their feature branches until they're ready.

Comment: @spikeheap is right. Considering this, and your requirement, your QA may not be willing to test develop. It would test a octopus merge of develop and all the other pending feature branches. This merge would be recreated each time a commit is pushed.

Comment: In my case, even a feature is complete, it's not target for release this week, maybe it will be postponed to next release